Why are not all classes of dependency imported?
I am working on a legacy android project and trying to import the dependency
com.vanniktech:android-image-cropper:4.3.3

The dependency is loaded without errors or warnings however when importing e.g.
import com.canhub.cropper.CropImage;

I am getting Cannot resolve symbol CropImage. When looking at the package, you can see that a lot of classes are missing:

Any idea what the reason might be? I have the same issue regardless of the package version I import. My project is configured with gradle 7 and kotlin 1.7.20. The app itself is written in Java.

Are you sure that class is actually available in that version of the artifact? You can manually download the JAR/AAR from Maven Central and unzip it to see if the class is there or not, that would help you figure out whether it's a Gradle issue or not.

@Egor I downloaded the arr from here https://maven.moxtra.com/nexus/content/groups/public/com/vanniktech/android-image-cropper/4.3.3/ It contains yet another classes.jar with the class I want to import. Is this strcture normal or an error on the dependency side?

Yep, that sounds like the normal package structure.

From a quick go including the lib in an empty project, the classes seem to be loaded correctly (I went for the latest version but same holds true for 4.3.3).
That points to the issue being related to gradle or something in the local environment, some bits to double check:

Is the package you're looking at (in the above screen) part of the External Libraries (Project View in AS shows them separately) or part of your own "App"? (if the latter, drop the package and sync gradle deps again)
Did you try cleaning? (ie. ./gradlew clean / AS "Invalidate caches and restart")
Did you check your dependency graph (./gradlew dependencies) to verify some other dependency isn't importing an older version of the same lib?



Thanks, that got me on the right path. My kotlin version was older than what the library was using.
